# Creating Model URL for Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to using core data to save and load my data that I get from server:

```
 private lazy var managedObjectModel : NSManagedObjectModel = {
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(self.manageObjectModelName, withExtension:"mom")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()
```

I have an error

> unexpectedly found nil

while unwrapping an Optional value in this code. And my `persistanceStoreCooardinator` storage and `mainQueueContext` storage are nil.
How can solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typo in this line `mom` instead of `momd`:

```
let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(self.manageObjectModelName, withExtension:"momd")!
```